# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}x^{n} + ... + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{o}}dx$ via Residue Theory?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, improper-integrals, contour-integration

In the text "Functions of a Complex Variable" by Robert E. Greene and Steven G.Krantz I'm having trouble verifying my solution to $\text{Problem (1)}$

> $\text{Problem (1)}$
>
> Using Calculus of Residue evaluate the following
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}x^{n} + ... + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{o}}dx \, \, \, $$
>
> $\text{Remark}$
>
> $p(x)$ is any polynomial with no zero's on the nonnegative real axis

$\text{Solution}$

For $(1)$ real variable methods would be fruitless we have to take the,

$$\oint_{\eta_{R}} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz.$$

For our choice $f$, we initially let

$$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \eta_{R}^{1}(t)  =  t + i/\sqrt{2R},  \, \, \, \,   1/\sqrt{2R} \leq t \leq R,$$

$$\eta_{R}^{2}(t)= Re^{it}, \, \, \, \,  \theta_{0} \leq t \leq 2 \pi - \theta_{0},$$

where $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0}(R) = \sin^{-1}(1/(R \sqrt{2R}))$

$$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \eta_{R}^{3}(t)  =  R -t -i/\sqrt{2R},  \, \, \, \, 0 \leq t \leq R-1/\sqrt{2R}.$$

$$\eta_{R}^{4}(t)  =  e^{it}/\sqrt{R}, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \pi/4 \leq t \leq 7 \pi /4.$$

It's important to consider that,

$$\oint_{\eta_{R}} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz = 2 \pi i \bigg( \sum_{j} \operatorname{Ind_{\eta_{R}}}(P_{j}) \cdot \operatorname{Res_{\eta_{R}}}(P_{j}) \bigg) $$

Clearly our choice of $f$ has a pole of the order of $P$ and a pole of the order $n$. Clearly,

\begin{align*} 
\operatorname{Res_{f}(P)} &=  \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \bigg( \partial_{z} \bigg)^{n-1} \bigg( (z-n)^{n} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}\bigg) \bigg|_{z=P}\\ 
\, \, \,  &=  \frac{1}{(n)!} \bigg( \partial_{z} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}x^{n} + ... + a_{n}z^{2} + a_{o}}\bigg|_{z = P} \bigg) \\
 &= \frac{1}{(n!)}\frac{\log(z) - a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}P^{2} + a_{o}}{(\log(x)^{2})}\\   &= \frac{1}{(n!)}\frac{\log(P) - a_{n}P^{n} + ... + a_{2}P^{2} + a_{o}}{(\log(P)^{2})}.
\end{align*}

Putting the pieces together,

$(*)$
$$\oint_{\eta_{R}} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz  = 2 \pi i \bigg(  \frac{1}{(n!)}\frac{\log(P) - a_{n}P^{n} + ... + a_{2}P^{2} + a_{o}}{(\log(P)^{2})} \bigg) \cdot 1$$

Applying the  Residue Theorem unfortunately isn't enough to finish our game so it becomes imperative to claim that

$(**)$

$$ \Bigg| \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{\eta^{2}_{R}} f(z)dz \Bigg| \rightarrow 0 $$

and that,

$(***)$

$$ \Bigg| \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{\eta^{4}_{R}} f(z)dz\Bigg| \rightarrow 0.$$

A particular device used to justify convergence over $\eta_{4}$ and $\eta_{2}$ is the fact that

$$\bigg(\log \bigg( \frac{x + i \sqrt{2R}}{(x-i/\sqrt{2R}} \bigg) \bigg)\rightarrow -2 \pi i \text{.}$$

We will return to this particular device after dealing with our analysis of convergence over $\eta_{4}$ and $\eta_{2}$. First we take that,

$$\sum_{\psi}^{4} \bigg(\oint_{\eta_{R}^{\psi}} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz \bigg). $$

Now over $\eta_{2}$ one can see that,

\begin{align*}
\bigg| \oint_{\eta_{R}^{2}}\frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz\bigg|& = \bigg| \int_{-R}^{+Ri} \frac{\log(Re^{it})}{a_{n}(Re^{it})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(Re^{it})^{2} + a_{o}} iRe^{i \theta} d \theta\bigg|\\&=  \int_{-R}^{+Ri} \bigg|\frac{\log(Re^{it})}{{a_{n}(Re^{it})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(Re^{it})^{2} + a_{o}}} \bigg| \big| iRe^{i \theta} d \theta \big|\\&= \int_{-R}^{+Ri} \frac{\bigg|\log(Re^{it}) \bigg|}{\bigg| {a_{n}(Re^{it})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(Re^{it})^{2} + a_{o}} \bigg|}  \bigg|iRe^{i \theta} \bigg| d \theta  \bigg| \\& = \int_{\theta_{0}}^{2 \pi - \theta_{0}} \frac{\bigg|\log(Re^{it}) \bigg|}{\bigg|{a_{n}(Re^{it})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(Re^{it})^{2} + a_{o}} \bigg|}  \bigg|iRe^{i \theta} \bigg| \bigg|d \theta  \bigg|.
\end{align*}

Now we can establish a precise estimate for $\eta_{2}$

$$\bigg| \oint_{\eta_{R}^{2}} \frac{\log(z)}{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}dz\bigg| \leq  \frac{\ln(R) + \pi }{R^{n} - a_{o}} \pi R \, \, \text{as} \, \, \, R \rightarrow \infty.$$

A similar process for $\eta_{4}$ says that,

\begin{align*}
\bigg| \oint_{\eta_{R}^{4}} \frac{\log(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})}{{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}}  dz\bigg|& =  \oint_{\eta_{R}^{4}} \bigg| \frac{\log(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})}{{a_{n}(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(e^{it}/ \sqrt{R})^{2} + a_{o}}}  iRe^{i \theta} d \theta\bigg|\\&= \oint_{\eta_{R}^{4}}  \frac{\bigg|\log(e^{it}/\sqrt{R}) \bigg|}{\bigg|a_{n}(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(e^{it}/ \sqrt{R})^{2} + a_{o} \bigg|}  iRe^{i \theta} d \theta \\&= \oint_{\eta_{R}^{4}}  \frac{\bigg| \log(e^{it})- \frac{1}{2}\log(R^{}) \bigg|}{ \bigg|a_{n}(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(e^{it}/ \sqrt{R})^{2} + a_{o} \bigg|} \bigg|  iRe^{i \theta} d \theta \bigg|\\& =\oint_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7 \pi}{4}}  \frac{\bigg| it\log(e^{})- \frac{1}{2}\log(R^{}) \bigg|}{ \bigg|a_{n}(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})^{n} + ... + a_{2}(e^{it}/ \sqrt{R})^{2} + a_{o}\bigg|} \bigg|  iRe^{i \theta}\bigg| d \theta \bigg|.  \end{align*}

Now we can establish a precise estimate for $\eta_{4}$ hence,

$$\bigg| \oint_{\eta_{R}^{4}} \frac{\log(e^{it}/\sqrt{R})}{{a_{n}z^{n} + ... + a_{2}z^{2} + a_{o}}}  dz\bigg|   \leq  \text{length}(\eta_{R}^{4})  \cdot \sup_{\eta_{R}^{4}}(g) \leq \pi R \frac{O(\log(R))}{\sqrt{R}} \, \text{as} \, R \rightarrow \infty.$$

By taking care to provide estimates over $\eta_{2}$ and $\eta_{4}$ we have proved $(***)$ and $(**)$.

Applying Szeto's Lemma it becomes apparent that,

$(****)$
$$\oint_{\eta^{1}_{R}}g(z) dz + \oint_{\eta^{3}_{R}}g(z) dz \rightarrow  - 2 \pi i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}t^{n} + ... + a_{2}t^{2} + a_{o}}dx \, \, \,$$

Now taking $(*)$, $(**)$, $(***)$, $(****)$ taken together yield,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}x^{n} + ... + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{o}}dx = 2 \pi i \bigg(  \frac{1}{(n!)}\frac{\log(P) - a_{n}P^{n} + ... + a_{2}P^{2} + a_{o}}{(\log(P)^{2})} \bigg)$$

Comment: Now looking at the proof I suspect that if one provides a $\delta-\epsilon$ definitions  of $\eta_{R}$ it should clean up some of the analysis made. Could anyone assist with this ?

Comment: First, is the term $a_1x$ missing from $p_n(x)$?  Second, why do you believe that $f(z)$ has poles of any particular order?

Comment: @MarkViola hmm the fact that our particular choice of $f$ is very erroneous on my part, I'll have to answer with a correct proof sometime later. But diving into the meat of the issue is that our problem  in $(1)$ the integral we are considering is correctly written as

$(1)$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p(x)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{1}x + a_{o} }dx $$


Applying the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $(1)$ can be rewritten as

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2}) \cdot \cdot \cdot (x-x_{n})}dx$$

Comment: What is $f$? What is $P$? It would be a shame if the only people who could follow this were precisely those who could reproduce it at will! (I am not such a person.)

Comment: What exactly do you expect for an answer?  Almost everywhere you say you want $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{p(x)}$.  And then, you also say you want $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{p(x)}$. These two integrals cannot be dealt with in the same manner.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{p(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials with real coefficients and

I.
$$
deg(P(x))\leq deg(Q(x))-2
$$
and

II. $Q(x)$ have no roots $z_j$ in $\textbf{R}=(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Assume that $c$ is a simple closed curve that contains all roots in the upper plane and $\gamma_R$ is the sigment $[-R,R]$, $R>0$, along with 
$$
\delta(R):=\left\{z\in\textbf{C}:|z|=R\textrm{ and }0\leq arg(z)\leq \pi \right\},
$$ 
then if $\gamma_R$ encloses $c$, we can write:
$$
\oint_c\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz=\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz=\int^{R}_{-R}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx+\int_{\delta(R)}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz
$$
From (I) exist $M>0$ and $z_0\in \textbf{C}$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\right|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^2}\textrm{, }\forall |z|>|z_0|.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}\left|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz\right|\leq \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\gamma_R}\left|\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\right||dz|\leq
\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{M}{R^2}\int_{\gamma}|dz|=
$$
$$
=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{M}{R^2}\pi R=0.
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{R}_{-R}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx+\int_{\delta(R)}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz=\oint_{c}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz=2\pi i\sum^{n}_{j=1}Res\left[\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)},z_j\right],
$$
where $z_j$ are the roots of $Q(z)=0$ in the upper plane. Taking the limit $R\rightarrow +\infty$, we arive to
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}dx=2\pi i\sum^{n}_{j=1}Res\left[\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)},z_j\right],
$$
which is the desired result.

Note that $n$ are the number of distinct roots (without counting multiplicity) in the upper plane.

If we set $R(z):=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$, then

i) If $z_0$ is a pole of first class, we have
$$
Res\left[R(z),z_0\right]=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\left((z-z_0)R(z)\right).
$$

ii) If $z_0$ is a pole of higher class$-k$, where $k$ integer greater than 1, then
$$
Res\left[R(z),z_0\right]=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\left(\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}(z-z_0)^k R(z)\right).
$$

CONTINUING NOTE.

Assume now the differential equation
$$
y'(x)=\sum^{N}_{n=1}a_ny(x)^n=H(y(x))
$$
This differential equation have solution
$$
x+C=\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{\log(y(x)-\rho)}{H'(\rho)},
$$
where the summation is taken over all roots of $H(x)=0$, (here $H$ is a simple polynomial function). If we invert $y$ we get
$$
y^{(-1)}(x)=\int\frac{1}{H(x)}dx=\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{\log(x-\rho)}{H'(\rho)}.
$$
Hence given a polynomial $H(x)$, with simple roots$-\rho$, then 
$$
\int\frac{1}{H(x)}dx=\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{\log(x-\rho)}{H'(\rho)}+C_1
$$
Now I use a lemma

Lemma (Mathematical Olympiad, Poland 1979)

Let $H(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $N>1$ with simple distinct roots $\rho_1,\rho_2,\ldots,\rho_N$. Then
$$
\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{1}{H'(\rho)}=0.
$$

From the above lemma we have
$$
S(h):=\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{\log(h-\rho)}{H'(\rho)}=\sum^{N-1}_{k=1}\frac{\log(h-\rho_k)}{H'(\rho_k)}+\frac{1}{H'(\rho_N)}\log(h-\rho_N)=
$$
$$
=\sum^{N-1}_{k=1}\frac{\log(h-\rho_k)}{H'(\rho_k)}-\sum^{N-1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{H'(\rho_k)}\log(h-\rho_N)=\sum^{N-1}_{k=1}\frac{\log(h-\rho_k)-\log(h-\rho_N)}{H'(\rho_k)}
$$
From which (easily) one can see that
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow+\infty}S(h)=0.
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dt}{H(t)}=-\sum_{\rho/H}\frac{\log(-\rho)}{H'(\rho)}.
$$
$qed$

Hence knowing that $H(x)=a(x-\rho_1)(x-\rho_2)\ldots (x-\rho_N)$ is a polynomial with simple roots, then the following formula (1) give us the value of 
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dt}{a(t-\rho_1)(t-\rho_2)\ldots(t-\rho_N)}=-\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{\log(-\rho_k)}{H'(\rho_k)}
$$

Comment: Isn't the required integral from $0$ to $\infty$, and not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?  How does your work deal with the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}dx$ for instance?

Comment: I have add some notes for the case of simple roots polynomial, with degree>1.

Comment: It's been a couple of months and I've just gotten back to read this working through your solution and a question that comes to mind. Consider $P(X)$, and $(Q(x)$ being polynomials of degree $N > 1$ with simple roots $\rho_1,\rho_2,\ldots,\rho_N$, also note that $deg(Q(z)) > deg(P(z))$ could one generalize that, 


$$\sum_{\rho/H / P}\frac{Q'(p)}{P'(\rho)}=0.$$

Comment: @ Zophikel. Yes: If $P(z)$ is polynomial of degree $N>1$ and has distinct roots in $\textbf{C}:,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_N$, then we have $\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{z_k^r}{P'(Z_k)}=0$, $\forall r=0,1,2,\ldots,N-2$.

Comment: so a better way I could have written this to make it more clear is if $Q(z)$, and $P(z)$ are polynomials of degree $N>1$ and has distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}:$ (i.e) we have $\textbf{C}:,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_N$ it trivially follows that, 

$$\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{Q'(Z_k)}{P'(Z_k)}=0, \forall r=0,1,2,\ldots,N-2.$$


Now probing the result and doing some thinking, makes me wonder if one could also say as well that , 


$$\sum^{N}_{k=1}\frac{Q'(Z_k)a}{P'(Z_k)}=0, \forall r=0,1,2,\ldots,N-2. $$


$\text{Remark}$

$a$ is just some constant

Comment: Also another question I have about the result is why did you introduce the differential equation were you deriving or proofing the lemma, because it seems after you introduce the lemma you apply it the question at hand

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 2$ whose roots are in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.  The goal is to evaluate 
$$I:=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_k\in\mathbb{C}$ be all pairwise distinct roots of $p(X)$, respectively, with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k$ (whence $n=m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_k$).  Define $f:\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\right)\to\mathbb{C}$ to be the holomorphic function
$$f(z):=\frac{\ln(z)}{p(z)}\text{ for all }z\in\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\right)\,.$$
Here, for a complex number $z\in\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\right)$, we write $z=r\,\exp(\text{i}\phi)$ with $\phi\in(0,2\pi)$ and $r>0$, and then define
$$\ln(z):=\ln(r)+\text{i}\phi\,,$$
so that the branch cut is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.  For $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, set
$$J(\epsilon):=\oint_{\Gamma_{\epsilon}}\,f(z)\,\text{d}z\,,$$
where $\Gamma_{\epsilon}$ is the positively oriented keyhole contour given by
$$\begin{align}\Biggr[\epsilon\,\exp(+\text{i}\epsilon),\frac{1}{\epsilon}\,\exp(+\text{i}\epsilon)\Biggl]&\cup\Biggl\{\frac{1}{\epsilon}\,\exp(\text{i}\theta)\,\Big|\,\theta\in[\epsilon,2\pi-\epsilon]\Biggr\}\\&\cup\Biggr[\frac1\epsilon\,\exp(-\text{i}\epsilon),{\epsilon}\,\exp(-\text{i}\epsilon)\Biggl]\cup\Biggl\{{\epsilon}\,\exp(\text{i}\theta)\,\Big|\,\theta\in[2\pi-\epsilon,\epsilon]\Biggr\}\,.\end{align}$$

Observe that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,J(\epsilon)=-2\pi\text{i}\,I\,.$$
By the Residue Theorem,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,J(\epsilon)=2\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^k\,\text{Res}_{z=z_j}\big(f(z)\big)\,.$$
Hence,
$$I=-\sum_{j=1}^k\,\text{Res}_{z=z_j}\big(f(z)\big)\,.$$
Since 
$$\begin{align}\text{Res}_{z=z_j}\big(f(z)\big)&=\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\Big(\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,f(z)\Big)\\&=\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)\end{align}$$
for $j=1,2,\ldots,k$, we conclude that
$$I=-\sum_{j=1}^k\,\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)\,.\tag{*}$$
In particular, if $m_j=1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,k$, then $k=n$ and
$$I=-\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{\ln\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,.\tag{$\star$}$$

For example, let $p(X):=\left(X^2+1\right)^2\,(X+1)$.  You can see that the partial fraction decomposition gives
$$\int\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{8}\,\left(\frac{2\,(x+1)}{x^2+1}-\ln\left(x^2+1\right)+2\,\ln(x+1)+4\,\arctan(x)\right)+\text{constant}\,,$$
so that
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{4}\,(\pi-1)\,.$$
You can also use (*) to compute $I$.  Let $z_1=-1$, $z_2=+\text{i}$, and $z_3=-\text{i}$, so that $m_1=1$, $m_2=2$, and $m_3=2$.  Then,
$$\frac{1}{\left(m_1-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_1}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_1-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_1-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_1\right)^{m_1}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)=\lim_{z\to -1}\,\frac{\ln(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{4}\,,$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\left(m_2-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_2}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_2-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_2-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_2\right)^{m_2}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)&=\lim_{z\to +\text{i}}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\,\frac{\ln(z)}{(z+\text{i})^2\,(z+1)}\\&=\frac{1+\pi}{8}-\text{i}\,\left(\frac{\pi-2}{16}\right)\,,\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\left(m_3-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_3}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_3-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_3-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_3\right)^{m_3}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)&=\lim_{z\to -\text{i}}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\,\frac{\ln(z)}{(z-\text{i})^2\,(z+1)}\\&=\frac{1-3\pi}{8}-\text{i}\,\left(\frac{3\pi+2}{16}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$I=-\left(\frac{\pi\text{i}}{4}+\left(\frac{1+\pi}{8}-\text{i}\,\left(\frac{\pi-2}{16}\right)^{\vphantom{a^a}}\right)+\left(\frac{1-3\pi}{8}-\text{i}\,\left(\frac{3\pi+2}{16}\right)^{\vphantom{a^a}}\right)^{\vphantom{a^a}}\right)=\frac{\pi-1}{4}\,.$$

---

In fact, if $m_j=1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,k$ (so $k=n$), then it follows that
$$\frac{1}{p(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)\,\left(x-z_j\right)}\,.$$
Without loss of generality, we assume that
$$\text{arg}\left(z_1\right)\geq \text{arg}\left(z_2\right) \geq \ldots \geq \text{arg}\left(z_n\right)\,,$$
wher $\text{arg}(z)$ is the argument of $z\in\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\right)$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$.  Because $$\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\,\frac{x}{p(x)}=0\,,$$ we can write
$$\frac{1}{p(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,\left(\frac{1}{x-z_j}-\frac{1}{x-z_n}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$\int\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,\ln\left(\frac{x-z_j}{x-z_n}\right)+\text{constant}=\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,\ln\left(x-z_j\right)+\text{constant}\,,$$
whence
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,\ln\left(\frac{z_j}{z_n}\right)=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\,\frac{\ln\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,.$$
For example, one can evaluate $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}\,\text{d}x$$ to be
$$-\left(\frac{\ln(-2)}{(-2+3)}+\frac{\ln(-3)}{(-3+2)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\,.$$

---

If $s(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-2$ such that $p(X)$ and $s(X)$ do not share a common factor, then $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x$$
can be evaluated in the same way.  That is, we have
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=-\sum_{j=1}^k\,\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,\ln(z)\,s(z)}{p(z)}\right)\,.$$
In particular, if $m_j=1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,k$ (so $k=n$), then 
$$\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{s\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)\,\left(x-z_j\right)}$$
and so
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=-\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{\ln\left(z_j\right)\,s\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)}\,.$$

Comment: It looks like you posted nearly the same answer twice. Was this intended?

Comment: @AlexR.  They are not the same answers (one has the extra assumption that $p(X)$ is an even polynomial, and the other deals with a more general setting).  And I intended to do this, because MathJax is very slow for long answers.

Comment: I've been reworking through your proof I apologize for the late response(it's been a couple of months), but why isn't okay to end the proof by noticing that, 

$$ \int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}dx= -\sum_{j=1}^k\,\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,\ln(z)}{p(z)}\right)\,.\tag{*} $$

Comment: I initially ask because it seems $(*)$ would work for any order pole while  $\tag{$\star$}$ seems to work for the cause of first order poles ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ be a nonconstant polynomial whose roots are in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.  If $p(X)$ has only even powers of $X$ (i.e., $p(X)=q\left(X^2\right)$ for some nonconstant polynomial $q(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$), then the answer can be made simpler.  Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_l$ be the roots of $p(X)$ in the upper half plane $$\mathbb{H}^+:=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,\text{Im}(z)>0\big\}\,,$$
respectively, with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_l$.  (Thus, $p(X)$ also has $-z_1,-z_2,\ldots,-z_l$ as roots, respectively, with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_l$.  Ergo, $n=2\,\left(m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_l\right)$, where $n$ is the degree of $p(X)$, which must be an even positive integer.)

For $R>0$, consider the contour positively oriented contour $C_R$ given by
$$[-R,+R]\cup\big\{R\,\exp(\text{i}t)\,\big|\,t\in[0,\pi]\big\}\,.$$
Let
$$I:=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x\text{ and }K(R):=\oint_{C_R}\,\frac{1}{p(z)}\,\text{d}z\,.$$
Thus,
$$2I=\lim_{R\to\infty}\,K(R)=2\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^{l}\,\text{Res}_{z=z_j}\left(\frac{1}{p(z)}\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$I=\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{1}{\left(m_l-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}}{p(z)}\,.\tag{$\square$}$$
In particular, if $m_j=1$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots,l$, then we get $l=\dfrac{n}{2}$ and
$$I=\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{1}{p'\left(z_j\right)}=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}\,\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{1}{z_j\,q'\left(z_j^2\right)}\,.\tag{#}$$
Note that (#) can be proven by ($\star$) from my other answer.  Similarly, ($\square$) also follows from (*).

For example, if $p(X)=\left(X^2+1\right)\,\left(X^2+4\right)$, then $q(X)=(X+1)\,(X+4)$.  You can use the partial fraction decomposition to get
$$\int\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{6}\,\Biggl(2\,\arctan(x)-\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\Biggr)+\text{constant}\,,$$
so that
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{12}\,.$$
However, using (#), we get 
$$I=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}\,\left(\frac{1}{\text{i}\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2\text{i}\cdot(-3)}\right)=\frac{\pi}{12}\,.$$

On the other hand, if $p(X)=\left(X^2+1\right)^3$, then we need to use ($\square$).  Note that $l=1$, with $z_1=\text{i}$ and $m_1=3$.  Hence,
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}\,\text{d}x$$
equals
$$\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2!}\,\lim_{z\to\text{i}}\,\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}z^2}\,\frac{1}{(z+\text{i})^3}=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}\,\left(\frac{12}{(2\text{i})^5}\right)=\frac{3\pi}{16}\,.$$
Using the partial fraction decomposition yields
$$\int\,\frac{1}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{8}\,\left(\frac{x\,\left(3\,x^2+5\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+3\,\arctan(x)\right)+\text{constant}\,,$$
so we get the same answer $I=\dfrac{3\pi}{16}$.

---

Indeed, if $m_j=1$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots,l$ (so $l=\dfrac{n}{2}$), then 
$$\frac{1}{p(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{2\,z_j}{p'\left(z_j\right)\,\left(x^2-z_j^2\right)}=\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{1}{q'\left(z_j^2\right)\,\left(x^2-z_j^2\right)}\,.$$  This provides an alternative proof of (#).

---

If $s(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-2$ such that $p(X)$ and $s(X)$ do not have a common factor, and if $s(X)$ only has even-degree terms (namely, $s(X)=u\left(X^2\right)$ for some $u(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$), then we also have
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{1}{\left(m_l-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,s(z)}{p(z)}\,.$$
In particular, if $m_j=1$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots,l$, then $l=\dfrac{n}{2}$ and
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\pi\text{i}\,\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{s\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)}=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}\,\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\frac{u\left(z_j^2\right)}{z_j\,q'\left(z_j^2\right)}\,.$$

Comment: Let $d>1$ be an integer.  Suppose that $p(X)=q\left(X^d\right)$ and $s(X)=u\left(X^d\right)$ for some $q(X),u(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ with $\deg(q)>\deg(u)$, and that $p(X)$ and $s(X)$ share no common roots.  Assume further that $p(X)$ has no nonnegative real roots.  Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_l$ be all the distinct roots of $p(X)$ with arguments in the interval $\left(0,\dfrac{2\pi}{d}\right)$, respectively, with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_l$.

Comment: We can then show that $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\small\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d}\right)}\,\sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,s(z)}{p(z)}\,.$$

Comment: In particular, if $m_j=1$ for every $j=1,2\ldots,l$, then $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{s(x)}{p(x)}\,\text{d}x=\small\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d}\right)}\,\sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{s\left(z_j\right)}{p'\left(z_j\right)}=\frac{\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d}}{1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d}\right)}\,\sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{u\left(z_j^d\right)}{z_j^{d-1}\,q'\left(z_j^d\right)}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

> $\text{Batominovski's First Idenity}:$
>
> Let $d > 1$ be an integer. Suppose that $p(X) = q(X^{d})$ and $s(X) = u(X^{d})$ for some $q(X)$, $u(X) \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ with $deg(q) > deg(u)$, and that $p(X)$ and $s(X)$ share no common roots. Assume further that $p(X)$ has no nonnegative real roots. Let $z_{1}, z_{2}, …, z_{n}$ be all the distinct roots of $p(X)$ with arguments in the interval $(0, \frac{2 \pi}{d})$, respectively, with multiplicities $m_{1}, m_{2}, …, m_{n}$ one can then show that
>
> $(*)$
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{s(x)}{p(x)}dx = \frac{2 \pi i}{1 - \exp( \frac{2 \pi  i}{d})} \sum_{j}^{l} \frac{1}{(m_{j} -1)!} \! \! \! \! \, \, \lim_{z \rightarrow z_{j}} \big( \partial_{z} \big)^{m_{j}-1} \frac{(z-z_{j})^{m_{j}}s(z)}{p(z)}.$$

$\text{Proof}$

Before embarking on our journey to conquer the Conjecture, first we must make some adjustments to our integral on the RHS side of $(*)$, so notice that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{s(x)}{p(x)}dx =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3}) \cdot \cdot \cdot (x-x_{n})}{a(z-z_{1})(z-z_{2})(z-z_{3}) \cdot \cdot \cdot (z-z_{n})}dx$$

$$ \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  = \frac{2 \pi i}{1 - \exp( \frac{2 \pi  i}{d})} \sum_{j}^{l} \frac{1}{(m_{j} -1)!}\lim_{z \rightarrow z_{j}} \big( \partial_{z} \big)^{m_{j}-1} \frac{(z-z_{j})^{m_{j}}s(z)}{p(z)} $$

Now it's important to note that our choice of $f$ is analytic on an open set $\psi$ containing the closed upper half plane,

$$ \mathcal{H} = \Big\{ z \in \mathcal{C} | \operatorname{Im(z)} \geq 0 \Big\}.$$
Furthermore consider that $R >0$ the positively oriented contour positively oriented contour $\phi_{R} \subset \mathcal{H}$ given by

$$\big[-R, +R \big] \bigcup \big\{R \, \exp(it)| t \in [0, \pi] \big\}.$$

Now to begin on our quest we make a note that $\phi_{R} \subset \mathcal{H}$, and consider

$$\oint_{\phi_{R_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{s(z)}{q(z)}dz$$

Now notice that,

$$\oint_{\phi_{R_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{s(z)}{q(z)}dz= 2 \pi i \bigg( \sum  \mathcal{Res_{f}(P_{j}}) \cdot \operatorname{Ind_{\gamma}}(P_{j}) \bigg)$$

$$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,   = 2 \pi i \bigg[ \sum_{j=1}^l\,\frac{1}{\left(m_j-1\right)!}\,\lim_{z\to z_j}\,\frac{\text{d}^{m_j-1}}{\text{d}z^{m_j-1}}\,\left(\frac{\left(z-z_j\right)^{m_j}\,p(z)}{p(z)}\right) \bigg].$$

Now for every if $m_{j} = 1$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots,l$ then we get $l=\dfrac{2 \pi}{d}$ so we now have that,

$\text{#}$

$$ \oint_{\phi_{R_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{s(z)}{q(z)}dz = \frac{2 \pi i}{1 - \exp( \frac{2 \pi  i}{d})} \sum_{j}^{l} \frac{1}{(m_{j} -1)!}\lim_{z \rightarrow z_{j}} \big( \partial_{z} \big)^{m_{j}-1} \frac{(z-z_{j})^{m_{j}}s(z)}{p(z)}.$$

To prove $\text{#}$ notice that if $m_{j} = 1$ for every $j =1,2,..l$ we have that

$$ \frac{s(x)}{p(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{2 \pi}{d}}\,\frac{d(s'(x_{j})) \, \big(x^{d}-x_{j}^{d})}{p'\left(z_j\right)\,\left(z^d-z_j^d\right)} =  \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{2 \pi}{d}}\,\frac{u'\left(z_j^d\right)\,\left(x^d-z_j^d\right)}{q'\left(z_j^d\right)\,\left(x^d-z_j^d\right)}.$$

Now unfortunately what we done at this point isn't enough to realize a full proof of the conjecture we still need to make a road-trip around $\phi_{R}.$ We can begin making this journey by noticing through Cauchy's Theorem that,

$$\oint_{\phi_{R_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{s(z)}{p(z)}dz = \oint_{\phi_{R^1_{\mathcal{H}}}}\frac{s(z)}{p(z)}dz  + \oint_{\phi_{R^{2}_{\mathcal{H}}}}\frac{s(z)}{p(z)}dz.$$

Now it's worthwhile to claim that,

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R^{1}_{\mathcal{H}}}}\frac{s(z)}{p(z)}dz \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{c} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx + \int_{c}^{\infty} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx  \, \, \text{as} \, R \rightarrow \infty.$$

Before one start's making any qualms make note using the tringle inequality for our choice of $p(z)$, since $|z| > R$ we have that,

$$|p(z)| \leq |a_{m}z^{m}| + \cdot \cdot \cdot |a_{1}z| + |a_{o}| \leq |a_{m}|R^{m} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + |a_{1}|R + |a_{o}|.$$

On a similar note,

$$|s(z)| \leq |b_{m}x^{m}| + \cdot \cdot \cdot |b_{1}x| + |b_{o}| \leq |b_{m}|R^{m} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + |b_{1}|R + |b_{o}|.$$

After taking care of $p(z)$, and $s(z)$ respectively we have the estimate,

$$|f(z)| = \frac{|f(z)|}{|q(z)|} \leq \frac{|b_{m}|R^{m} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + |b_{1}|R + |b_{o}|}{|a_{n}|R^{n}/2} \leq \frac{M}{R^{n-m}}.$$

Now we have the following,

$$\bigg| \oint_{\phi_{R^{2}_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz \bigg| \leq \frac{M(2 \pi R)}{R^{n-m}} = \frac{2M \pi}{R^{n-m-1}}.$$

It's to safe to say that,

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \bigg| \oint_{\phi_{R^{2}_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)} \bigg| \rightarrow 0.$$

Putting everything together it's easy to note that,

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{R_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz =  \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{\gamma_{R^{1}_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz + \oint_{\gamma_{R^{2}_{\mathcal{H}}}} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz  $$

$$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, = \frac{2 \pi i}{1 - \exp( \frac{2 \pi  i}{d})} \sum_{j}^{l} \frac{1}{(m_{j} -1)!}\lim_{z \rightarrow z_{j}} \big( \partial_{z} \big)^{m_{j}-1} \frac{(z-z_{j})^{m_{j}}s(z)}{p(z)}.$$